# Remove all break line CRLF if there is no space in font of it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this text:

```
Today is Monday  
Tomorrow is Tuesday
Sunday was beautiful,
and sunshine  
Goodbye.
```

You can see spaces (denoted as .) and breakline (denoted as CRLF) as this image below:

[image]

I want to do this:

- If there is a space in front of CRLF (breakline) then do nothing (keep the CRLF)
- Else if there is not a space in front of CRLF (breakline) then remove the CRLF (join 2 lines to 1)

So the result I want to accomplish looks like this:

```
Today is Monday  
Tomorrow is TuesdaySunday was beautiful,and sunshine  
Goodbye.
```

[image]

I tried this regex: `^[^\r\n]*\r\n` and replaced it with nothing but it is not working, it removed everything.

What will be the good regex for this?

Comment: Just `(?<!\s)\R`? Or `(?<!\s)\R+`... and replace with empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `^[^\r\n]*\r\n` matches a full line with trailing `\r\n`. So, you remove a whole line if you replace with an empty string.

Instead of hardcoding the newline sequence, you can use `\R` construct.

If you want to match something not preceded with some subpattern, you need to use a negative lookbehind. Here, a `(?<!\h)` should do (not any horizontal whitespace).

So,  use

```
(?<!\h)\R
```

If you have multiple linebreaks, add a `+` quantifier:

```
(?<!\h)\R+
```

The replacement will be an empty string.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could replace any character that is not a space followed by a CRLF with that character. So search for `([^ ])\r\n` and replace with `\1`. But this will probably process blank lines wrongly. So `([^ \r\n])\r\n` may be a better search string.